# How to disable the previous Dates in WPFToolkit DateTimePicker?

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, datepicker

In our current Project we are using the `WPFToolkit DateTimePicker`, Its having lot of events that we are using instead of `WPF DatePicker`. But there is one problem with this control. We cannot disabled the previous dates. We don't want the user to select the previous dates in the calendar, Suppose the `DatePicker` name is `ExDatePicker` but we cannot write `ExDatePicker.MinDate = DateTime.Today` or `DateTime.Now` in the `ExDatePicker.Loaded` method.

Can we do anything else to disable the previous dates? In `WPF DatePicker` we have one option `dateTimePicker.MinDate = DateTime.Now;`

I am missing this feature very much. Help or suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an older version of the WPFToolkit you have to update because the fixed this issue some month ago: [Add Mininum/Maximum properties in DateTimeUpDown](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/17944)

Comment: They have fixed in the `DateTimeUpDown` but they have not fixed that in DateTimePicker. They could have implemented BlackoutDates Property in case of previous dates.